# JWT authentication API spring Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have got a trouble with a test I am having.
I want to make an authentication JWT with spring.
But I am not a java developper.
I grab some stuff on the internet
the result is coded here : https://github.come/etouraille/boat

Previously I had a rest API that was working, but when I haded the jwt things not working anymore
When I curl Localhost I have got no return from the api

`curl -v localhost:8080/boats/99`

Please some one help me managing my rest authenticated API

Kind Regards

Comment: The example is on Github ... juste clone It. Cheers. sorry for the url : https://github.com/etouraille/boat

Comment: It is expected that the problem can be reproduced solely from the content of the question, not external links. If the code does not fit in the question, then you have not created a **minimal** example.

Comment: I understand. Could you make an exception ? I Will afterwards answer the question with the proper content. and explaining the errors.

Comment: provided you might give me minimal hints.